# Find $P(x_2/x_3 \leq a)$ where $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n $ are iid $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n $ be independent uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

How to find $P(x_2/x_3 \leq a)$?

---

Can I consider $$ x_2, x_3 $$ as two random variables or do I need to do something special? my attempt is below

$$f(x_2, x_3) = 1$$

$$P(\frac {x_2}{x_3} \leq a) = \int _0^{1} \int _0^{a*x_3} dx_2 dx_3 = \frac{a}{2} $$

---

**Edit**, I need to find the probability by conditioning. S my approach is not right.

---

**Update**: after reviewing the comments below, I summarized them into:

$$P\left(\frac {x_2}{x_3} \leq a\right) =  \begin{cases} 
\int_0^1 \int_0^{a*x_3}   dx_2 dx_3 = a/2 && a \le 1\\
\int_0^1 \int_1^{x_2/a}   dx_3 dx_2 = 1 - \frac{1}{2*a} && a > 1
\end{cases}
$$

these results are somewhat different from some of the comments below and they are not obtained by conditioning, however, they seem to be aligned with Mathematica results

I'm still thinking of the best way to get these results using conditional probability

Comment: Looks like you are just seeking the distribution of the ratio of any 2 independent standard Uniform random variables.

Comment: $\color{red}{\text{i}}$id = $\color{red}{\text{independent}}$ and identically distributed. Being independent, if an iid variable doesn't appear in the expression for determining a probability, you can simply forget it.

Comment: Your approach seems good for $a \le 1$. You need $dx_3$ In there instead of $dy$.

Comment: @Macavity, I don't have any limits on a. Do you just mean that for a>0 it's 0 (which is a standard art)? but how do i do it by conditioning?

Comment: @wolfies, wolfies, thank you for putting it in words. so does my approach make sense? I don't understand how to do it by conditioning

Comment: Your answer is now correct, though the inner integral for case $a>1$ needs to flip limits. Check, if you evaluate the integral you wrote, you will the negative of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  You should reason that (for positive a)
$$P\left(\frac {x_2}{x_3} \leq a\right) = \int _0^{1} \min(a \,x_3, 1) \, dx_3 =  \begin{cases} 
\int_0^1 a \, x_3 \, dx_3 && a \le 1\\
\int _0^{\frac1a} a \, x_3 \, dx_3 + \int _{\frac1a}^{1} 1 \, dx_3 && a > 1
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in\left(0,1\right)$ we have by independency:

$P\left\{ X_{1}/X_{2}\leq a\mid X_{2}=x\right\} =P\left\{ X_{1}\leq ax\right\} $

So if function $f$ is defined by $f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }ax\geq1\\
0 & \text{if }ax\leq0\\
ax & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then:

$P\left\{ X_{1}/X_{2}\leq a\mid X_{2}\right\} =f\left(X_{2}\right)$
and $P\left\{ X_{1}/X_{2}\leq a\right\} =\mathbb{E}f\left(X_{2}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx$

Comment: thank you, but why is the answer different from the above?

Comment: It is not different. Under the extra conditions $a>0$ the function
$f$ defined in my answer coincides on $\left(0,1\right)$ with $\min\left(ax,1\right)$
mentioned in the answer of Macavity. My answer is a bit more general
(it leaves open the possibility that $a<0$) and secondly it leaves
a bit more to you (I didn't work out the integration that far as Macavity
did). Macavity is right in excluding a\leq0 though. I am just a bit lazier.